# Build a DoWorkEventHandler from a string

Tags: c#, reflection, backgroundworker

I have a list of Actions.

```
public class Action {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DoWorkEventHandler DoWork{ get; set; }
}
```

That is populated on code.

```
list.Add(new Action("Name", SomeRandomMethod));
...
```

When someone chooses an Action from that list it will execute the respective action.

```
private void ListBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    var item = (Action) ListBoxScripts.SelectedItem;
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += item.DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

But I want to define and build this list from a DB. So How should I create an Action with a DoWorkEventHandler parameter when what I got from the DB is a string with the method name?

Comment: `Action` is a poor name for an application type because it is used by the BCL ([`System.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx))

Comment: This could definitely be done using reflection, but I don't think this is necessarily the best thing to be doing. If you're not careful someone could change your database contents to execute something you're not expecting/malicious... If the list of actions is a known set, then using an id to represent the action and changing behaviour based on that value would be better. If the actions can be defined dynamically, then you're probably looking for more of a plug-in architecture.

Comment: If the handlers are in a (set of) known class(es) you can filter them out with reflection. Or build a dictionary yourself.

Comment: To guard against what @Mike points out, you could define an Enum of possible values, then have a readonly dictionary of mappings from enum to MethodInfo (built on startup via reflection). Maybe you could create an attribute to decorate methods with as an alternative or addition to an enum dictionary.

Comment: @Richard the actual name is not Action and I also don't have a method named "SomeRandomMethod". It was just names to expose my problem

Comment: @Mike despite all of the security issues, I want to place them on a database (or a config file) because I building the application to multiple clients so I need an easy way to define what each client will get. It's all about a decision from the pick 2 from cheap, fast and good.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you could do this.

You could declare an `enum` containing all method names that are allowed to be called, then on startup using reflection build a dictionary mapping `enums` to `methodinfo`'s. You'd store the enum in the database.

Another option would be to decorate classes/methods as below:

```
[ContainsScriptableMethod("MyClassIdentifyingName"] // or a number
class MyUserScriptableMethods
{
    [ScriptableMethod("MyMethodIdentifyingName")] // Or just a number as an identifier
    void MyMethod()
    {
        // Do non-malicious stuff.
    }
}
```

When looking up a method to call you'd get a class ID from the database, then use reflection to get all classes that have the `[ContainsScriptableMethod]` attribute with the correct Id, then do the same for looking up the method.

You could just have an attribute for the method if there's only a few defined classes that have methods that can be called/scripted.

Example code below:

```
// Enumerate all classes with the ContainsScriptableMethod like so
foreach(var ClassWithAttribute in GetTypesWithAttribute(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), typeof(ContainsScriptableMethodAttribute))
{
    // Loop through each method in the class with the attribute
    foreach(var MethodWithAttribute in GetMethodsWithAttribute(ClassWithAttribute, ScriptableMethodAttribute))
    {
        // You now have information about a method that can be called. Use Attribute.GetCustomAttribute to get the ID of this method, then add it to a dictionary, or invoke it directly.
    }
}

static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesWithAttribute(Assembly assembly, Type AttributeType)
{
    foreach(Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.GetCustomAttributes(AttributeType, true).Length > 0)
        {
            yield return type;
        }
    }
} 

static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetMethodsWithAttribute(Type ClassType, Type AttributeType)
{
    foreach(var Method in ClassType.GetMethods())
    {
        if (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(AttributeType) != null)
        {
            yield Method;
        } 
   }
}
```

Comment: can you show an example of how to build the list with the ScriptableMethods solution?